# What is JavaScript Operator precedence -right to left meaning

Tags: javascript

I tried this JavaScript expression.

I got the answer.

But I need the logic behind that.

```
var x=8 ,y=5;
document.write(x++ + ++x - y++ - y-- );
```

How to evaluate this?

Comment: What research have you done? What do you think the logic is, if you break this into parts and work it out? Which part are you having trouble with? Both [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/javascript) and [the spec](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/7.0/index.html) are good resources (the latter is quite...obtuse).

Comment: Why not just look on this website? This isn't a problem with source code. The only problem here is lack of research. https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_operators.asp

Comment: `8 + 10 - 5 - 6 = 7`

Comment: how to close this question? i am stumped.....!

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it does not show any research effort.

Answer (score 0):

inside a statement

```
++x  // <-- increments x, then performs the statement
x++  // <-- performs the statement, then increments x


var x=8 ,y=5;
document.write(x++ + ++x - y++ - y-- );
```

Means

```
var x=8 ,y=5;
document.write(8 + 9 - 5 - 5 );
```

Whose result is 7

After that statement `x = 10` and `y = 5`